# Add one more level of indirection in ownership description: "Peter teacher's car"?

Tags: grammar, possessives

If I want to describe a car owned by Peter, I will say "Peter's car".

But how do I describe the car his teacher owns? "Peter teacher's car" or do I have to be descriptive: "the car of Peter's teacher"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't forget your apostrophes to indicate possession.

I would say "Peter's teacher's car" is fine.  You could even extend it to "Peter's teacher's car's seat's cushion" if you wanted, but it isn't very elegant.

Comment: I though that possession is written without apostrophe. From the basic example it's (it is) vs. its (something belonging to it).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: That's one of the _exceptions_ to the rule.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: the apostrophe in "it's" (it is) is to indicate the omission of the second letter i.  As Mr. Shiny and New said, the _possessive_ "its" is an exception to the rule and hence the apostrophe is omitted, despite it indicating possession.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be:  Other exceptions include "their" instead of the incorrect "they's", and "our" instead of the incorrect "us's".